# Isolating a microservice to API Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have microservices that are deployed in kubernetes. These microservices have 2 endpoints. One direct endpoint which has been exposed via ingress. Also the service has been exposed with API endpoint.

I am trying to configure my ingress in a way that only microservices would be accessed from API Gateway and no access from direct endpoint.

I am also using NGINX as my ingress controller.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Is nginx ingress controller a hard requirement?

Comment: Yes, @MariuszK. it is a hard requirment. In addition. 
To add more information, I have a load balancer after the API_Gatway and I need to pass loadbalancer with IPs of API_Gateway.